# Trigger to silently ignore/delete duplicate entries on INSERT

Tags: mysql, triggers, duplicates, constraints

I have the following table:
T(ID primary key, A, B)

I want to have pair (A, B) unique but I don't want to have constraint unique(A,B) on them because it will give error on insert.
Instead I want MySQL to silently ignore such inserts.

I can't use "insert on duplicate keys ignore" because I can't control client's queries.

So, can I build such trigger? Or maybe there is some constraint that allows silent ignore?

Edit: I dug around and I think I want something like SQLite's ["Raise Ignore"](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html#undef_before) statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before mysql 5.5. it wasn't possible to stop an insert inside a trigger. There where some ugly work arounds but nothing I would recommend. Since 5.5 you can use [SIGNAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) to do it.

```
delimiter //
drop trigger if exists aborting_trigger //
create trigger aborting_trigger before insert on t
for each row
begin
  set @found := false;
  select true into @found from t where a=new.a and b=new.b;

  if @found then
    signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'duplicate insert';
    end if;
  end   //

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thanks, but is this really 'silent' method? When I run insert it just gives different error number with different message. I tried changing SQLSTATE to 02 (warning), but this doesn't prevent tuple from insertion.

Comment: Correction, it gives me 'ERROR 1172 (42000): Result consisted of more than one row' in case of warning signal in trigger.

Comment: No, it won't be silent. Sorry, I missed that part. What I did was enforce a "unique" without the actual key...  There are no clean ways around this. My best suggestion is to have another table where the triggers inserts more data and that you read from that one. So one write table and one read table managed from the trigger. That won't work good with ORM though. Another alternative is to change the value of a and b to something out of scope, like a 999999 and make sure the client doesn't accept that combination.

Answer (score 3):

Add a unique key (A,B) and use INSERT statement with an IGNORE keyword.

From the reference - *If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are treated as warnings instead*.

[INSERT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html).

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I cannot control client's queries, so I have to deal with plain Inserts. The main reason is that queries are made through ORM.

Comment: Can you not modify a user's query before its run to add the ignore keyword?

Comment: I have one code-base and two databases (test and deployment), so I'd rather edit test database and not touch code-base at all.