# How do I implement a trigger in MYSQL to prevent insertion when row has duplicate data?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE preferences(
    user_id INT,
    hot_sid INT,
    not_sid INT,
)Engine = InnoDB;


CREATE TRIGGER check_show_comparison
AFTER INSERT ON preferences
REFERENCING NEW ROW
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN ( hot_sid = not_sid )
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

So I am trying to set up a database using MYSQL to keep track of something similar to hot or not. The actual purpose doesn't really matter, but basically I have a table called preferences with three columns, the first being the user id and the second and third column being preference ids where they represent the same kind of objects. (Going with the hot or not example, the hot_sid will store the id of the "hot" entity and the not_sid will store the id of the "not" entity. These two entities are the same type).

I am trying to write a trigger on each insertion to the table to prevent someone from adding a row that would have the same sid for hot and not. What am I doing wrong when implementing this check constraint? I thought about just using check constraint but I don't believe they are actually enforced in MYSQL.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208667/trigger-to-silently-ignore-delete-duplicate-entries-on-insert

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101680/sql-trigger-to-stop-duplicates-across-row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right - check constraints are are supported in DDL in MySQL, but the are ignored.
From the reference - *The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines*.

The solution is to create a BEFORE INSERT trigger, check new values and throw an error from the trigger if needed.

To raise the error you can use:

- [SIGNAL statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal-resignal.html): `SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'hot_sid = not_sid';`
- call nonexistent stored procedure: `CALL proc_error();`